# How to `find` with `-regex` in shell on a Mac

Tags: shell

I'm trying to build a bash code line that finds some files for me in a directory.

The (image) filenames are like this:

```
yyyy-mm-dd_hh_mm_ss.xxx.jpg
```

I want all files from:

Year: 2012, Month: 02-12, Time: 08:00-16:00

Theres a file for each minute of the day for all days of 2012.

I tried the following to start with, but it doesn't find anything:

```
find . -regex './2012-11-11_(0[8-9]|1[0-6])_*_*.*.jpg' | wc -l
```

I need to change the `11-11` to match all days, I know, but got stuck already on matching the time.

I've been reading somewhere that I need to specify `-regextype posix-extended`, but it doesn't know this option, and there isn't an alternative in the manual either.

Comment: not strictly an answer but http://txt2re.com/index-cpcre.php3 is really good for constructing tricky regex

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're confusing `regexp` and `shell globbing`.

Replace the `*` with `.*` (or better, with `\d{2}` - two digits), the `.` with `\.` (as `.` means *any character*), etc.

Reading some regexp documentation would be great.

Comment: This is somewhat the explanation of the correct regex posted by @anubhava, because you were first and this is more learning, I'll mark this as the right answer. ;)

Answer (score 2):

Use this regex based find on OSX:

```
find -E . -regex '\./2012-(0[2-9]|1[0-2])-[^-]+_(0[8-9]|1[0-6])_.*\.jpg'
```

Comment: Almost, I guess you have a typo in `[12]`, it's missing a dash. Other than that it works like a charm! Thanks!

Comment: I had `1[12]` to match months `11` and `12`

Comment: Oh wait, it matches `1` and `2`.. So doesn't need a range! My bad!

Comment: Though I think it should be: `(0[2-9]|1[0-2])` earlier one will miss out month 10

Comment: Note to future incoming Google searchers: by Mojave, this answer appears to be outdated. Running `find -E . -regex '\.(jpe*g|png|gif)'` in a folder full of images turns up 0 results. You need `find -E . -regex '.*\.(jpe*g|png|gif)'`.

Comment: @JohnSmith: My answer doesn't have `find -E . -regex '\.(jpe*g|png|gif)'` so how is it outdated?

Answer (score 1):

I think this is not business with regex. You just want find files between 2 time stamps, so you can touch 2 files, change those 2 files' modified time to 2012-02-01 and 2012-12-01.

then use "find -cnewer  file1 and ! -cnewer file2 " to find out those files you need. also -cmin -ctime maybe can used.